# What does it mean that the conversion operator is "still valid" in a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, conversion-operator

```
class Game {
  class Other {}; // Nested class
  // Automatic type conversion:
  operator Other() const {
    cout << "Game::operator Other()\n";
    return Other();
  }
};    
class Chess : public Game {};
void f(Game::Other) {}
int main()
{
    Chess d;
    f(d);
}
```

I'm reading the "thinking in c++" chapter 14--functions that don't automatically inherit.
The above code fragment is an example given by Eckel. And Eckel said:

> "Because of all these rules about rewriting functions that handle
>   object creation, it may seem a little strange at first that the
>   automatic type conversion operator is inherited. But it's not too
>   unreasonable-if there are enough pieces in Game to make an Other
>   object, those pieces are still there in anything derived from Game and
>   the type conversion operator is still valid(even though you may in
>   fact want to redefine it)."

I don't understand what Eckel tries to say. Can anyone explain it more detail?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is saying that, unlike some other similar things, type conversion operators *are* automatically inherited by derived classes.

His argument for why this behaviour is reasonable is that if you can construct an `Other` from a `Game`, you can also construct an `Other` from anything that "is a" `Game` (i.e. a derived class).